# "Extraction failed: unknown error" when running `gcloud artifacts docker images scan` from Docker Container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm attempting to run [`gcloud artifacts docker images scan`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/docker/images/scan) from a Docker container.

```bash
docker run --rm -it \
  --read-only --volume "$HOME/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud" \
  --entrypoint /bin/bash \
  google/cloud-sdk:latest
```

The exact command is `gcloud artifacts docker images scan $IMAGE --remote --location=us`. But I'm getting the following error (with `--verbosity=debug` added for more output):

```bash
root@aaa50fa5cb97:/# gcloud artifacts docker images scan $IMAGE --remote --location=us --verbosity=debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.artifacts.docker.images.scan] with arguments: [--location: "us", --remote: "True", --verbosity: "debug", RESOURCE_URI: $IMAGE]
⠛ Scanning container image                                                                                                  
  ⠛ Locally extracting packages and versions from remote container image                                                    
  . Remotely initiating analysis of packages and versions                                                                   
X Scanning container image                                                                                                  
  X Locally extracting packages and versions from remote container image $IMAGE, '--remote=True', '--provide_fake_results=False', '--undefok=additional_package_types,verbose_errors']
Failed.                                                                                                                     
DEBUG: (gcloud.artifacts.docker.images.scan) Extraction failed: unknown error (exit code: 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 987, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/artifacts/docker/images/scan.py", line 186, in Run
    tracker.FailStage('extract',
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/console/progress_tracker.py", line 940, in FailStage
    raise failure_exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
googlecloudsdk.command_lib.artifacts.ondemandscanning_util.ExtractionFailedError: Extraction failed: unknown error (exit code: 2)
ERROR: (gcloud.artifacts.docker.images.scan) Extraction failed: unknown error (exit code: 2)
```

The command is running with no issues on my machine, and other commands such as [`gcloud artifacts docker images list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/docker/images/list) returns results as expected when run from the container.

Since other `gcloud` commands work as expected, I don't *think* it's related to authentication. I expect the scan command to successfully extract the packages without errors.

Comment: Try upgrading gcloud version using 'gcloud components update' commmand.

Comment: Same error output, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you manually input `LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY-ID/IMAGE[:tag]`. I managed to replicate, and encountered no issue.

Comment: You mean you're able to get a shell in the `google/cloud-sdk:latest` container and run `gcloud artifacts docker images scan LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY-ID/IMAGE[:tag] --remote --location=us` with no issue?

I've tried this, is that what you mean by manual input?

Comment: Try running the command with a different container image to see if the issue is specific to the image you are trying to scan.

Comment: Still no luck, no matter which image.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out! Was having the same issue as you and nothing online seemed to help. In my case, I had a `serviceAccount` that had only the `roles/ondemandscanning.admin` IAM permission in GCP, as stated in the [on-demand scanning documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/os-scanning-on-demand).

It kept failing on the `Locally extracting packages and versions from remote container image` step. I tried running it with a "super-admin" `serviceAccount` and this time the local extraction step worked but then failed with a permission error at the on-demand scanning step!

#### The fix

Although it's undocumented, it kind of makes sense: your on-demand scanning `serviceAccount` must also have `artifactRegistry` permissions. I've given it `admin` as a test and it worked, but I'm assuming `reader` would be sufficient.

Comment: This sounds like it could my issue too. I'll check it out and accept the answer if everything works. Thanks!

Comment: Still no luck, failing at the extraction step no matter what roles I grant the service account.

Comment: hmm and you're able to get this to work outside of the container but not inside the container correct? or are you just never able to get it to work?

Comment: Works entirely fine outside the container. Beginning to think something is up with my Docker installation.